# If a paper is on ResearchGate, can it always be submitted to arXiv?

Tags: publications, arxiv

Would there be any reason a paper cannot be submitted to arXiv if it's already on ResearchGate (assuming it's on an topic accepted by arXiv)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

Many (perhaps even most?) papers on ResearchGate are posted there in violation of copyright agreements with traditional publishers.  Those papers cannot be published on arXiv, because doing so would violate the same copyright agreements.

Comment: If a publisher already approved posting a paper on ResearchGate, would arXiv then be fine?

Comment: Your bold text and your normal text disagree. Don't your mean _yes_, there is a reason .... and then state that reason? As it stands your answer says there is _No_ reason a paper on ResearchGate cannot be submitted to arXiv, then states a reason anyway.

Comment: @Gypsy The bold text answers the title question which is phrased in the opposite way of the question in the body.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I tend to ignore the title after reading the question. Valid point. Never tried to figure out how to answer a question where title and text ask opposite questions.